# Codeigniter Session resets when refreshing

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

After a month trying to solve this, and trying all kind of answers in related questions I decide to ask it myself.

This problems occurs on a new server we recently bought, the same code it's working fine on localhost and last server. But it's probably code related.

The Session is correctly created and the token is set, a var_dump shows that. But when the users tries to login, after redirecting to the access function, the Session token is not set, so the login doesn't occurs.

Even on the same page, if you refresh, the __ci_last_regenerate (which get the time when the Session was regenerated for last time) is the current time, and change after every single refresh.

In var/lib/php/session two different files are created after every refresh, don't know why. Here the pic:

[image]

The one at 19 secs hast the correct data (time and token), the last one only the time.

**Also, we recently add a new subdomain to the site, so we have in the same server two different subdomains.**

This is the Session configuration:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Tried also with DB driver, and it generated 2 (or 3 rows sometimes) on the table. The config was:

```
$config['sess_driver']= 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name']= 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']= 0;
$config['sess_save_path']= 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']= FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']= 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy']= FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']= TRUE;
$config['sess_expire_on_close']= TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']= 'ci_sessions';
```

And the output of database being its columns (id, ip, timestamp, data):

[image]

The data is always the same, a last regenerate containing the time and a token in one case, and only the last regenerate in the other (2 rows on each refresh).

PHP is 7.2.7 . CodeIgniter is 3.1.5.

Any further code needed or server information will be supplied if asked.

**Edit 4/9:**
Also adding these cookie data, as asked by some users.

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = '.my-domain.com';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

Comment: thanks! your "Edit 4/9" gave me a hint to change the cookie domain into the new one, finally, it helped me.
$config['cookie_domain']    = '.my-domain.com';

Comment: mine solved by change the php version to 7.0 and modifying the base_url , because it must redirect to https not http,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem was the Apache conf in our Centos 7 with the two subdomains.

We had both VirtualHost data inside the same httpd conf file. The fix was to create a different conf file for each domain. Something like:

domain1.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain1.com
  ServerAlias domain1
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domain1-error_log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domain1-access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And the same for the domain2.

Hope this can help anyone.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not storing session data anywhere but in the user's cookie, as it seems that your config reads

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
```

Since you're using the `files` driver, you should specify a location for the session data to be stored in the server. By default (out of the box), CodeIgniter is set-up like this:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'ci_session/';
```

you need to specify a directory to which CodeIgniter can write to. Otherwise, if the session data is not stored in the server, whenever you try to do anything, the session in the cookie will not match against anything.

Remember, CI sessions are not exactly the same as native PHP sessions.

Furthermore, as CI itself states in the config:

```
|   'sess_save_path'
|
|   The location to save sessions to, driver dependent.
|
|   For the 'files' driver, it's a path to a writable directory.
|   WARNING: Only absolute paths are supported!
|
|   For the 'database' driver, it's a table name.
|   Please read up the manual for the format with other session drivers.
|
|   IMPORTANT: You are REQUIRED to set a valid save path!
```

UPDATE (Aug. 31 2018) Based on the updates you made to the original question:

There a a couple of un-needed/redundant settings in the session config when using database. These are all you need, anything extra on your setup should go away:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

I don't think that this is the case, but please check your code for any place you may be calling the native `session_start()` function. Doing so makes CI session management behave unpredictably and one of the symptoms is that sessions do not persist (I learned this the hard way, spent around a month debugging until I found a single session_start call that was messing everything up)

Can you please check if the `data` column in the sessions table is actually being written? (another symptom of the above). Try running this and if everything is returned as "empty", we may be getting closer:

```
select
case
when cast(data as char(1000)) = '' then "empty"
else "something"
end as content, count(*)
from ci_sessions group by content;
```

Also, keep in mind that actually creating the sessions table is not sufficient. Did you run the `ALTER` that's required depending on your `sess_match_ip` setting?

Comment: Allready tried it:

Message: Session: Configured save path '/var/www/html/desarrollo.cice.vuce.gob.ar/application/ci_session' is not writable by the PHP process.

Even when it's 0777

Comment: That's a different problem, but it doesn't mean you shouldn't set a save path.

Aside from setting the correct permissions (0777 may help debugging, but remember it shouldn't be the long term solution) you may run into trouble if you don't write to disk using the correct user (codeigniter runs on your web user permissions, but the writing to disk is done by apache or nginx, so the whole directory and its contents must be owned by the apache/nginx user)

I had a similar issue when I started using Codeigniter for this same reason, chown'd the directory to www-data (nginx user) and voila

Comment: If you check your old server, you'll see that the save path is set and the directory ownership is not the default one....that said, If you visualize that at any point in the future you may need to have multiple app servers and a load balancer in front of them, it would be better to future-proof yourself right now and use another session driver (database, redis or memcached). It'll save you a lot of pain in the future

Comment: Changed to database driver, so the data is saved, and the problem is still there...

Comment: Could you post your updated session configuration and the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ci_sessions` (or whatever name you assigned to the table)?

Comment: $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

this worked for me it creates new sessions files but work as expected idk why but when true session gets destroyed if two or more refresh if clicked. ty

Answer (score 1):

-make sure you initialized session library only once

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

-make sure it isn't autoloaded

```
application/config/autoload.php
```

- call `session_write_close()` once you no longer need anything to do with session variables if you are using codeigniter version 3

-make sure you neither `unset( $_SESSION );` nor destroyed it

```
session_destroy();

// or

$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

-sessions are affected by those cookies configurations `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = '.your-domain.com';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using http server so set config_secure = false otherwise your session will be  expired on every page refresh

check below

```
   $config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
   $config['cookie_domain'] = '';
   $config['cookie_path'] = '/';
   $config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
   $config['cookie_httponly']   = FALSE;
```